# iframe "ajax-like" file upload - preview

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to include a picture uploader in a already existing submission form - Ideally I want it to appear ajax-like so obviously the iframe is the way to go- once uploaded I want it to show a preview of the image uploaded and leave the url for the location of the file in a hidden input

I found http://www.uploadify.com/demos/ which seems like it would be my best bet however I cant figure out how to make it display a preview image or leave the url in a hidden input.
preferably I want an "undo" button in case they selected the wrong file but I'm not picky

anyone know either how to make this happen or of a better option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return any information through the data argument of Uploadify's [onUploadSuccess](http://www.uploadify.comdocumentation/uploadify/onuploadsuccess/) event, including a file url.